# DateTimeEdit in QML like in Qtwidgets

Tags: qt, qml

In QtWidgets we have something called QDateTimeEdit like below image

[image]

do we have any thing similar in QML that does this? I searched online and could not find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent in QML. But, you can easily create your own widget with a TextField and a custom validator:

In QML:

```
TextField {
    text : "01/01/1970 00:00:00"
    inputMask: "99/99/9999 99:99:99"
    validator: DateTimeValidator {}
    }
```

In C++:

```
// datetimevalidator.h
#include <QValidator>
#include <QDateTime>

class DateTimeValidator: public QValidator
{
public:
    DateTimeValidator();

    State validate(QString& input, int& pos) const;
};
```

```
// datetimevalidator.cpp
#include <datetimevalidator.h>
DateTimeValidator::DateTimeValidator(): QValidator()
{}

QValidator::State DateTimeValidator::validate(QString& input, int& pos) const
{
     QDateTime dt = QDateTime::fromString(input, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
     if (dt.isNull()) // If null, the input cannot be parsed
     {
         return QValidator::Invalid;
     }
     return QValidator::Acceptable;
}
```

In the main(), register your validator to be able to use it in QML:

```
#include "datetimevalidator.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    qmlRegisterType<DateTimeValidator>("my.components", 1, 0, "DateTimeValidator");
...
}
```

Comment: Hello, i could not make this work, created a qt quick application project and added QML file with the same content, created a c++ class file with the name DateTimeValidator and added the content, registered as you suggested, but it is throwing many errors..can you please help

Comment: expected class name, Unknown type name 'State' 
Should i create C++ class file or C++ Source file? Thanks for jumping in again

Comment: Add `#include <QValidator>`. Create a header file (.h). You can move the implementation in a source file, if you want.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and include the necessary things

Comment: I have added `import my.components 1.0` in qml and added the edited code, i am getting `use of undeclared identifier 'Datetimevalidator'` error now

Comment: It's case sensitive and you have to include your new header file in your *main.cpp*, also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192477/discussion-between-techiesoft-and-romha-korev).